# Specializing a template function with a generic class

Tags: c++, template-specialization

I am writing a simple data to XML serializer for training purposes. The idea is to pass values to a serialize function that will do something to bring the given values into a string format. Many types do have built in conversions, but for many I want to have a specialized function doing this. My approach is:

I have a template function with this signature:

```
template <class T> void serialize(T *value, Serializer *serializer);
```

and I can specialize the template like this:

```
template <> void serialize<bool>(bool *value, Serializer *serializer);
```

Works fine. Now I want to write a serialize function for a vector, as in:

```
template <class T> void serialize<std::vector<T*> >(std::vector<T*> *value, Serializer *serializer) {
    serializer->begin_section("array");
    for(std::vector<T*>::iterator it = value->begin(); it != value->end(); it++) {
        serializer->add_value(*it);
    }
    serializer->end_section();
}
```

But when I compile it (g++ 4.6.2), I get `error: function template partial specialization ‘serialize<std::vector<T*> >’ is not allowed`. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you wish to provide a template specialization that is a template itself.

The simplest way to resolve your problem is to not use template specialization at all and instead rely on function overloading.

```
template<class T> void serialize(T *value, Serializer *serializer);
```

can still provide a default implementation, but if a more specialized version like

```
void serialize(bool *value, Serializer *serializer);
```

exists, it will be preferred by the overload resolution.
This allows you to simply define a function like

```
template <typename T> void serialize(::std::vector<T> *value, Serializer *serializer);
```

that will be called for vectors. (Consider that ::std::vector is more specialized than T, so overload resolution will pick this function where it is possible).

Answer (score 1):

You could overload `serialize()`, [for example](http://ideone.com/bKost):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class T> void serialize(T *, char *)
{
    std::cout << "T\n";
}

template <class T> void serialize(std::vector<T*> *, char *)
{
    std::cout << "vector\n";
}

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    std::vector<int*> x;

    serialize(&a, 0);
    serialize(&x, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
T
vector
```